# How specific to be in postdoc research statements?

Tags: postdocs, research-statement

I am a PhD student in a theoretical physics, preparing to apply for postdocs. Although some applications have more guidance for research statements, many simply say to include a "research statement." I've found advice on general length and tone, but something I'm not certain about is - how specific should I be in my future research plans? Presumably somewhere between the two extremes of "I think X is a cool field and want to work on it" and "here is a three year timeline of exactly how I am going to execute this project." But like, are they looking for fully-formed ideas where all that remains is for someone to sit down and do the math? Or can they be things with a higher probability of failure, like "I would like to try to come up with a model that does X and Y properties, which would be useful for such and such"?

Comment: Are you applying to a department or to a specific PI?

Comment: Currently the ones I'm looking at are department-wide - so I'm assuming the research statement should have more of a specific vision, but I'm still not sure to what extent.

Comment: Have you looked for examples and advice online?  There are plenty of both for math.